# Manipulating Select element on form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to programatically autofill my information on a form like [this](https://checkout.stripe.com/pay/ppage_1HCHEvFKnpzPB0MXjz2DgySV#fidkdWxOYHwnPyd1blpxYHZxWm9CPHY2XUhhVm9fQzxOYWgwYjA8f2lcYScpJ3dgY2B3d2B3SndsYmxrJz8nbXFxdXY%2FKip2cXdsdWArZmpoJyknaWpmZGlgJz9rcGlpKSdobGF2Jz9%2BJ2JwbGEnPydLRCcpJ2hwbGEnPyc9PWZmNjxgNCgyMTNjKDFkNmcoZDVhPSgxNTw1N2AyZD02MmQnKSd2bGEnPydLRCd4KSdnYHFkdic%2FXlh4JSUl) (Stripe's testing form) however I'm having trouble filling/selecting some of the fields.

For example, merely changing the Node's value attribute is not working for fields like the `cardNumber` field, and changing the `selectedIndex` attribute for the country does not have any effect.

Example:
`selectedIndex = 40` from another index like `3` gives you Canada, which when done manually, will cause a Postal Code field to appear. However, I'm having trouble achieving this programmatically by just changing the`selectedIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually dispatch an event:

```
var select = document.getElementById('billingCountry')

select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }))
```

Comment: Thanks! I've actually tried that without the `bubbles` setting which didn't work. What exactly does that do?

Comment: The event propagates through the DOM.

Comment: Thank you, although this doesnt work for inputting the card number for example. What extra steps would I need to take?

Comment: @JC1, what is the aim of this? If you want to do testing, look into https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer. It's a headless Chrome that helps test websites, but it will work fine in your case.

Comment: Automation to help ease the checkout process as some products do sell out rather fast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219160/discussion-between-jc1-and-adam-azad).